# How to optimize JS code?

Tags: javascript, optimization, profiling, google-chrome-devtools

Chrome profiling say: "Not optimized: assignment to parameter in arguments object". What can i do for optimize this code?

```
this.buffer.forEach(function(tilepos, ypos)
{
  tilepos.forEach(function(tileinfo, xpos)
  {
    _self.tiles.putTile('ground', xpos, ypos, _self.ground);
  });
});
```

Comment: Please provide the `putTile` method. The issue is probably in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It likely does not like that you are acting on `tilepos` within the block.

I would recommend doing it as follows if you wish to eliminate the error, but also get a bit of a performance boost:

```
for(var i = 0; i < this.buffer.length; i++)
{
    for(var j = 0; j < this.buffer[i].length; j++)
    {
        _self.tiles.putTile('ground', i, j, _self.ground);
    }
}
```

Comment: But buffer not always start from 0

Comment: If the buffer is an array, it should always start from 0

Comment: Use the for loops as the forEach function is very slow when compared to the for loop. Avoid sparse as some javascript engines will use a lookup to index elements which results in much slower code. So always start your array at index 0 and fill it sequentially. Adding a item out of sequence can turn the array into a sparse array.

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely overwriting the arguments by reassigning a function parameter or an arguments element.

```
function f(a) {
    a = 100; // reassigns arguments[0]
};
```

Or

```
function f(a) {
    arguments[0] = 100; // same thing
};
```

Your code looks fine to me, so I assume the problem lies in your `putTile` method. If you need to reassign the function parameters, create a local copy of it:

```
function f(a) {
    var localA = a;
    localA = 100;
}
```

If you provide the `putTile`method then I can take a look and update my answer.